# CSRF token not getting refreshed on location reload

Tags: javascript, laravel, csrf

I've got some js code that sends an axios delete request when a button is pressed and then refreshes the page by doing `window.location.reload(true)` but then if I try to press the button that does the axios delete request on a different section of the same page I get a 419 error, hinting at the CSRF token not being reloaded on the page refresh. If I do a manual refresh of the page after it works.

I've also tried doing a simple `window.location.href = '/previousurl` and that doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding the following to my bootstrap.js file

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## CSRF Tokens & JavaScript (from laravel docs)

When building JavaScript driven applications, it is convenient to have your JavaScript HTTP library automatically attach the CSRF token to every outgoing request. By default, the Axios HTTP library provided in the resources/js/bootstrap.js file automatically sends an X-XSRF-TOKEN header using the value of the encrypted XSRF-TOKEN cookie. If you are not using this library, you will need to manually configure this behavior for your application.

see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf for more information

Comment: That does not help me, as said sending the CSRF token is not the issue, the issue is the CSRF token is not getting refreshed on page reload when doing it with a js reload function